# I need to send an instruction to a game server

Tags: vb6

I need to send an instruction to a game server.

https://www.phoenixbse.com/index.php?a=turns&sa=gpi&ma=parse&id=11111

When just sent through crome this works fine, but am having difficulty getting VB6 to do this.

So far have tried:-

WebBrowser1.Navigate "https://www.phoenixbse.com/index.php?a=turns&sa=gpi&ma=parse&id=" & "111111"

But does not seem to work.

Help Please

Comment: Why do you have five `1s` in the chrome example but six `1s` in the VB6 example?

Comment: Bad Typing??  It is just a number, could be anything from 1 to 99999

Comment: Please adequately describe "doesn't work".  But it might be that the MS browser control by default runs in document mode 7, so the server will probably see this request coming from a very out of date IE7 (even though you've probably got IE11 on your pc). Making a registry change to override that default document mode 7 behavior might work - see https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/may/21/web-browser-control-specifying-the-ie-version for description on the registry `FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION` settings.

Comment: What is the error message? Is an exception thrown? Add in a try catch statement around the call to the game server and check the exception message.

Comment: When that command is sent through Chrome it instructs the game server to parse the position number "11111", which it does, but when sent through WebServer it does not. That is the "Doesn't Work" there is no error message,

To be perfectly honest I do not understand a lot of this. I bought VB6 back in the days of Windows XP and am completely self taught by trial and error.

Comment: I can download files from the games site fine with:-

WebBrowser1.Navigate "http://www.phoenixbse.com/index.php?a=xml&uid=285&code=380a7752fdbc0ec46eff6c502d14a36f&sa=turn_data&tid=" & "11111"
    Do Until WebBrowser1.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Loop
    strText = WebBrowser1.Document.body.innerhtmlSo just assumed that I could send a position number [the "11111" bit, but could be anything from 0 to 99999] by just using:-

WebBrowser1.Navigate "https://www.phoenixbse.com/index.php?a=turns&sa=gpi&ma=parse&id=" & "11111"

But evidently not.